# Only search the first few characters of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am looking to take the first 10 characters instead of taking the whole cell data. What I am attempting to do is make a google form where the only submission field is an ID (Ex `cfb1-12345`, where `cfb1` is the name of a tab in the sheet and `cfb1-12345` is the full ID) so that my app script command can take the first x number of characters (in the examples case 4) and substitute it for the "records" sheet name. I am doing this now by having a separate field with the tab name the script specifically searches for.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSht = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var recordsSht = ss.getSheetByName(formSht.getRange("B4").getValue());
```

As shown here, it currently gets this value from cell B4, but I would like to be able to take the first X number of characters to fill this field to find the correct sheet tab. Any help is appreciated as I am quite the beginner.

Also, if anyone knows how to delay google forms responses from updating a spreadsheet to leave a 15-second interval between submissions, I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve `cfb1` from `cfb1-12345` in a cell "B4" using Google Apps Script.

In this case, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var recordsSht = ss.getSheetByName(formSht.getRange("B4").getValue());
```

#### To:

```
var recordsSht = ss.getSheetByName(formSht.getRange("B4").getValue().split("-")[0].trim());
```

- By this, when `cfb1-12345` is put in the cell "B4", `formSht.getRange("B4").getValue().split("-")[0].trim()` returns `cfb1`.

#### Note:

- About `Also, if anyone knows how to delay google forms responses from updating a spreadsheet to leave a 15-second interval between submissions`, how about using `Utilities.sleep(15000)`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)